# Datepicker change format ufter updating

Tags: datepicker, yii2, format, bootstrap-datepicker, kartik-v

I am using the bootstrap datepicker in my view and every time I call the **update method**, the date sets fine but the date picker suddenly reverts from dd/mm/yyyy format to mm/dd/yyyy format.

**Controller**

```
public function actionDias(){
    Yii::$app->response->format = \yii\web\Response::FORMAT_JSON;

    if (isset($_POST['anio']) and isset($_POST['cuatrimestre'])) {
        $cuatrimestre = $_POST['cuatrimestre'];
        $anio = $_POST['anio'];

        $fechaMin = CampusActividadDia::find()->where(['cuatrimestre' => $cuatrimestre])->andWhere(['anio' => $anio])->min('fecha');
        $fecha_desde = date("d/m/Y", strtotime($fechaMin));

        $fechaMax = CampusActividadDia::find()->where(['cuatrimestre' => $cuatrimestre])->andWhere(['anio' => $anio])->max('fecha');
        $fecha_hasta = date("d/m/Y", strtotime($fechaMax));

        return ([
            'fecha_desde' => $fecha_desde,
            'fecha_hasta' => $fecha_hasta
        ]);
    } else return null;
}
```

**View**

```
<div id="dias" class="form-group hidden">     
    <label class="control-label">Rango de Fechas:</label>
    <?php  
    echo DatePicker::widget([
        'model' => $model,  
        'attribute' => 'fecha_desde',
        'attribute2' => 'fecha_hasta',
        'options' => ['id'=>'fecha_desde','disabled' => ($model->fecha_desde == "")],
        'options2' => ['id'=>'fecha_hasta','disabled' => ($model->fecha_desde == "")],
        'type' => DatePicker::TYPE_RANGE,
        'separator' => 'hasta',
        'pluginOptions' => [
            'autoclose' => true,
            'format' => 'dd/mm/yyyy'
        ]
    ]); ?>
</div>
```

**Js**

```
$.ajax({
    url: URL_BASE + "/campus/dias",
    type: "post",
    dataType: "json",
    data: { 
        cuatrimestre: this.value,
        anio: $('#anio').val()
    },
    success: function (res) {
        const fecha_desde = res.fecha_desde;
        const fecha_hasta = res.fecha_hasta
        
        $(fechaDesdeRef).kvDatepicker('update',new Date(fecha_desde));
        $(fechaHastaRef).kvDatepicker('update', new Date(fecha_hasta));

        $(fechaDesdeRef).prop('disabled', false);
        $(fechaHastaRef).prop('disabled', false);
    },
    error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
    alert("ERROR " + xhr.status);
    },
});
```

I've also tried to change date format both ways setting the global default format and locally but without success, like the following:

```
$.fn.kvDatepicker.defaults.format = 'dd/mm/yyyy'
$(datePickerRef).kvDatepicker({
    formatDate: 'd/m/Y',
    date:'d/m/Y'
})
```

I've also read this issue, but there isn't a conclution about it:

https://github.com/uxsolutions/bootstrap-datepicker/issues/1775

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like that your DatePicker is overwriting pluginOptions when model is loaded. Might need to config DatePicker or overwrite it to stop missing format

Answer (score 0):

config/main.php

```
'modules' => [
       'datecontrol' => [
        'class' => 'kartik\datecontrol\Module',
        'displaySettings' => [
            'date' => 'php:d-M-Y',
            'time' => 'php:H:i:s A',
            'datetime' => 'php:d-m-Y H:i:s A',
        ],
        'saveSettings' => [
            'date' => 'php:Y-m-d', 
            'time' => 'php:H:i:s',
            'datetime' => 'php:Y-m-d H:i:s',
        ],
        // automatically use kartikwidgets for each of the above formats
        'autoWidget' => true,      
     ],
],

'components' => [
//http://webtips.krajee.com/override-bootstrap-css-js-yii-2-0-widgets/
        'assetManager' => [
            'bundles' => [
                'yii\bootstrap4\BootstrapAsset' => [
                    'sourcePath' => '@npm/bootstrap/dist'
                ],
                'yii\bootstrap4\BootstrapPluginAsset' => [
                    'sourcePath' => '@npm/bootstrap/dist'
                ],
                '@frontend\modules\invoice\assets\CoreCustomCssJsAsset'=>[
                    'sourcePath' => '@frontend/modules/invoice/assets'
                ],
],
```

composer.json

```
 "require": {
        "php": ">=7.4.9",
        "guzzlehttp/guzzle":"*",
        "yiisoft/yii2": "~2.0.41.1",
        "yiisoft/yii2-bootstrap": "~2.0.9",
        "yiisoft/yii2-bootstrap4": "^2.0.8",
        "bower-asset/bootstrap": "~3.4.1",
        "bower-asset/ladda": "*",        
        "bower-asset/font-awesome": "~4.7.0.0",
        "npm-asset/jquery": "^2.2",
        "vlucas/phpdotenv": "*",
        "insolita/yii2-migration-generator": "~3.1",        
        "ifsnop/mysqldump-php": "*",
        "warrence/yii2-kartikgii": "dev-master",
        "kartik-v/yii2-bootstrap4-dropdown": "@dev",
        "kartik-v/bootstrap-fileinput": "dev-master",
        "kartik-v/yii2-editable": "@dev",
        "kartik-v/yii2-grid":"@dev",
        "kartik-v/yii2-widget-timepicker": "@dev",
        "kartik-v/yii2-date-range": "*",
        "kartik-v/yii2-social": "@dev",
        "kartik-v/yii2-dynagrid": "dev-master",
        "kartik-v/yii2-tree-manager": "@dev",
        "kartik-v/yii2-mpdf":"dev-master",
        "kartik-v/bootstrap-star-rating": "@dev",
        "kartik-v/yii2-slider": "dev-master",
        "kartik-v/yii2-number" : "@dev",
        "kartik-v/yii2-editors": "@dev",
        "kartik-v/yii2-validators": "dev-master",
    },
   "require-dev": {
        "yiisoft/yii2-debug": "~2.1.0",
        "yiisoft/yii2-gii": "~2.1.0",
        "yiisoft/yii2-faker": "~2.0.0",
        "codeception/codeception": "^4.0",
        "codeception/verify": "~0.5.0 || ~1.1.0"
    },
     "config": {
        "process-timeout": 1800
    },
    "fxp-asset": {
            "installer-paths": {
                "npm-asset-library": "vendor/npm-asset",
                "bower-asset-library": "vendor/bower-asset"
            }
    },
```

These settings have worked for me. You might considering modifying your AppAsset.php as follows to incorporate bootstrap 4.

```
<?php

namespace frontend\assets;

use yii\web\AssetBundle;
use yii\bootstrap4\BootstrapAsset;
use yii\web\YiiAsset;
use yii\web\JqueryAsset;
/**
 * Main frontend application asset bundle.
 */
class AppAsset extends AssetBundle
{
    
    public $sourcePath = '@app/assets/app';
    public $baseUrl = '@app';
    
    public $css = [        
        'css/site.css',
        '//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap-glyphicons.css',
        '//use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.3.1/css/all.css',
        '//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.9.0/css/all.min.css'
    ];
    
    public $js = [ 
                   '//kit.fontawesome.com/85ba10e8d4.js',
    ];
    
    public $depends = [
        BootstrapAsset::class,        
        YiiAsset::class,        
        JqueryAsset::class,
    ];
}
```